# AJAX POST returns complete PHP instead echoed string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i created a js function which gets called by certain action,

```
var getX3DListFromServer = function()
{
  var dataList;
 //var post = $.post('X3DHandling.php', {postState:"getList"}, 
 //function(data){
 //  dataList = data;
 //});
 //console.log(dataList);
 //
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'X3DHandling.php',
    data: {postState:"getList"},
    success: function(data){$('#result').html(data);},
    error: function(){alert('getting list error')},
  });

  return dataList;
}
```

the php contains the following code,

```
<?php
echo "Working";
?>
```

I thought that the string gets pushed into the div but instead the variable **data** contains the complete php. It seems like the php file got not intepreted in an appropiate way.

```
<div id="result" class="footer"><!--?php
echo "Working";
?--></div>
```

I did everything what other people described in videos or different entries - but I don't know what I did wrong.

I hoped to get a result like this:

```
<div id="result" class="footer">
echo "Working";
</div>
```

I hope you can help me - thank you for your time.

Comment: how is this being accessed, as `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:800//webbasedcad.html

Comment: Change the extension of your file to .php.

Comment: ok i have appended the full url to:
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:800/X3DHandling.php',

but it still doesnt work. it adds the complete php

Answer (score -1):

Do Something like:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "functions.php",
     data: {
        products: "products",
      },
      success: function (data) {
       console.log("received data: " + data);
      },
      error: function (err) {
       alert('error: ' + err);
      }
}); //END AJAX CALL
```

And in the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['products'])) {
  $MyProducts = $_POST['products'];
   //PHP FUNCTION CALL HERE FOR EXAMPLE
}
```

Comment: <?php
echo "Working";
?>